# Get total count of records with a mysql join and 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I have 2 tables that I am trying to join but I am not sure how to make it the most time efficient.

Tasks Table:

```
nid | created_by | claimed_by | urgent
1   |     11     |     22     |   1
2   |     22     |     33     |   1
3   |     33     |     11     |   1
1   |     11     |     43     |   0
1   |     11     |     44     |   1
```

Employee Table:

```
userid | name
  11   |  EmployeeA
  22   |  EmployeeB
  33   |  EmployeeC
```

Result I am trying to get:

```
userid | created_count | claimed_count | urgent_count
  11   |       3       |       1       |       3
  22   |       1       |       1       |       2
  33   |       1       |       1       |       2
```

`created_account` column will show total # of tasks created by that user.

`claimed_count` column will show total # of tasks claimed by that user.

`urgent_count` column will show total # of urgent tasks (created or claimed) by that user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just write the query and test it. Then, when it proves to be too slow, try to optimize it. If you don't succeed, you can post your attempt, along with the table structure, indexes, amounts of data and other relevant information that may help us find the bottleneck in your query. Currently this question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by breaking this up into pieces and then putting them back together. You can get the created_count and claimed_count using simple aggregation like this:

```
SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS created_count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY created_by;

SELECT claimed_by, COUNT(*) AS claimed_count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY claimed_by;
```

To get the urgent count for each employee, I would join the two tables on the condition that the employee is either the created_by or claimed_by column, and group by employee. Instead of counting, however, I would use `SUM()`. I am doing this because it appears each row will be either 0 or 1, so SUM() will effectively count all non-zero rows:

```
SELECT e.userid, SUM(t.urgent)
FROM employee e
JOIN task t ON e.userid IN (t.created_by, t.claimed_by)
GROUP BY e.userid;
```

Now that you have all the bits of data you need, you can use an outer join to join all of those subqueries to the employees table to get their counts. You can use the `COALESCE()` function to replace any null counts with 0:

```
SELECT e.userid, COALESCE(u.urgent_count, 0) AS urgent_count, COALESCE(crt.created_count, 0) AS created_count, COALESCE(clm.claimed_count, 0) AS claimed_count
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT e.userid, SUM(t.urgent) AS urgent_count
  FROM employee e
  JOIN task t ON e.userid IN (t.created_by, t.claimed_by)
  GROUP BY e.userid) u ON u.userid = e.userid
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT claimed_by, COUNT(*) AS claimed_count
  FROM task
  GROUP BY claimed_by) clm ON clm.claimed_by = e.userid
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS created_count
  FROM task
  GROUP BY created_by) crt ON crt.created_by = e.userid;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de1930/5) example.